# How to find OpenCV installed in /usr/local when building ROS node

Tags: opencv, cmake, opencv3.0, ros

I am using ROS Kinetic with OpenCV. I created a node that uses CUDA implemented algorithms of OpenCV (which are not available in the ros-kinetic-opencv3 package) so I compiled OpenCV from source with CUDA enabled and installed it in `/usr/local`.

To test if my `/usr/local` installation was working as expected (and if my code was correct) I created a program, outside of ROS, with the following `CMakeList.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(stereo_algorithms_testing)
set(ENV{OpenCV_DIR} "/usr/local")
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(include ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(stereo_algorithms main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(stereo_algorithms ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

When I run `cmake .`, I get the following output:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found CUDA: /usr/local/cuda (found suitable exact version "8.0") 
-- Found OpenCV: /usr/local (found version "3.2.0") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/degraw/Opencv_testing/stereo_algorithms/test
```

All is well, and the code runs as expected with no runtime errors.

Now when I use the same code in a ROS node I have the following `CMakeList.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(depth_calculator)
set(ENV{OpenCV_DIR} "/usr/local")
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED core highgui calib3d PATHS /usr/local NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS cv_bridge image_transport)
catkin_package()
include_directories(include ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(double_image_acq src/double_image_acquisition.cpp)
target_link_libraries(double_image_acq ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

Notice that I explicitly tell cmake to only look for OpenCV in `/usr/local`.
The output of `catkin_make` is:

```
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/degraw/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/degraw/catkin_ws/devel;/usr/local;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /home/degraw/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/degraw/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.6
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 2 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - depth_calculator
-- ~~  - zed_wrapper
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'depth_calculator'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(depth_calculator)
-- Found OpenCV: /opt/ros/kinetic (found version "3.2.0") found components:  core highgui calib3d 
...
...
...
Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/degraw/catkin_ws/build"
[ 14%] Built target zed_wrapper_gencfg
[ 28%] Linking CXX executable /home/degraw/catkin_ws/devel/lib/depth_calculator/double_image_acq
[ 57%] Built target ZEDWrapper
[ 85%] Built target zed_wrapper_node
CMakeFiles/double_image_acq.dir/src/double_image_acquisition.cpp.o: In function `OpencvDisparityCalculator::callback(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)':
double_image_acquisition.cpp:(.text._ZN25OpencvDisparityCalculator8callbackERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN11sensor_msgs6Image_ISaIvEEEEES9_[_ZN25OpencvDisparityCalculator8callbackERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN11sensor_msgs6Image_ISaIvEEEEES9_]+0x1ad): undefined reference to `cv::cuda::createStereoBM(int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
depth_calculator/CMakeFiles/double_image_acq.dir/build.make:175: recipe for target '/home/degraw/catkin_ws/devel/lib/depth_calculator/double_image_acq' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/degraw/catkin_ws/devel/lib/depth_calculator/double_image_acq] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:353: recipe for target 'depth_calculator/CMakeFiles/double_image_acq.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [depth_calculator/CMakeFiles/double_image_acq.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

Obviously it's a linker issue. It finds the wrong OpenCV (the ROS OpenCV) which does not include the libraries for CUDA.

How can I tell catkin_make to find the OpenCV in `/usr/local`?

Comment: With *NO_DEFAULT_PATH* `find_package()` should only search under *HINTS* and *PATH* options (it even ignores environment variables). I see the only way it could result with the `/opt/ros/kinetic` path: *cache* variable *OpenCV_DIR* is **already set** to that path. E.g., someone previously searched OpenCV or you forgot to clear the cache before reconfiguration attempt.

Comment: I would not have thought this in a million years! It worked, it finally found the OpenCV in /usr/local. Unfortunately, i still have the linking error, i will continue trying to find what's wrong, but now at least i am loading the correct OpenCV. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @Degraw! One year on, did you end up finding a solution to your problem? I'm in the same boat now and would love to hear how you fixed this issue.

Comment: Hi @MrSquid. Unfortunately, it has been a while and I can't even remember if I solved it. But one thing that pops to mind whenever I had similar issues, is that cleaning my catkin workspace and recompiling everything fixed some caching issues. I also remember at some point I did not have ROS OpenCV installed at all (or any of the packages depending on it, eg. cv_bridge, image_transport) but I use to add all those packages' source code to my catkin workspace and compile them, linking to my `/usr/local` OpenCV. Hope this helps after all this time!

Comment: I solved this issue myself too - the problem turned out to be quite obscure, a dependency that I was adding to my CMakeLists with catkin_simple also used OpenCV and was loading the ros install of OpenCV, thus overwriting the path that I was defining for my custom install. Thanks for the reply anyways :)